# Can someone give me a reality check on this video?

Tags: oscillators

https://www.facebook.com/DabungPakistan/videos/497292570459987/

This is a video in which a person keeps increasing his swing distance on a large swing (pendulum motion/simple harmonic motion) until he makes a complete circle.

What I find incredible in all this is that when he gets the swing angle more than 45° to the horizontal, he still manages to keep the swing behaving in a perfect pendulum motion. Instead of that, the swing should have *fallen* downwards straight until the tension of the rope re-initiated the pendulum motion. This is why I think a full swing in pendulum motion is impossible to achieve by gradually increasing the distance of each swing.

Can someone please verify my thoughts or show me otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: For those voting to close due to ambiguity, I am asking if the action of the swing in said video is possible in real life or not.

Comment: "... until the tension of the rope ..." - it's not a rope, it's a solid beam.

Comment: That is the very question. That whether it is possible to have this type of increasing swing distance possible **_with a rope_** or is it only possible with solid beams supporting the swing platform? @lemon

Comment: What you comment above is not the question you have written... "*What I find incredible in all this is that when he gets the swing angle more than 45° to the horizontal, he still manages to keep the swing behaving in a perfect pendulum motion.*" ... "*the swing should have fallen downwards straight until the tension of the rope re-initiated the pendulum motion.*" Since he is **not** using a rope but a rigid beam, as lemon mentions, there is nothing incredible about the video. With a rope the situation would indeed be different and not possible. Your thoughts are correct so far.

Comment: @YoustayIgo It is very unclear what you want.  In the first comment you say " I am asking if the action of the swing in said video is possible in real life or not." yet when given a reason you then say that's not your question?  Flagging as unclear.

Comment: Wait...so you're asking if the video that shows a real person looping around the swing is real? What evidence do you see that makes you think it's not?

Comment: I am asking if the action he is performing is real or not @KyleKanos  It appears to defy gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When considering the video with a rope examine the forces at the moment in time that you question. What are the forces on a rope and the weight. During the upward portion of the swing the rope would be in tension because the weight wants to travel in a straight line. If the pendulum were to stop at exactly horizontal at the top of the upswing and the rope had not stretched due to the tension the only force acting on the weight would be gravity and the direction of that force does not create tension on the rope nor does it attempt to compress it. Anything past horizontal and gravity will pull the weight in a direction that attempts to compress the rope. This of course would cause the rope to sag and the weight to fall in a straight line until it pulls the sag out of the rope. The rope would stay tight until the weight approaches the top of its trajectory. Then the weight of the rope would begin to pull it off it's circular path due to the effect of gravity overcoming the forces of inertia on a pendulum (commonly called centripetal forces).

I hope this helps.

Drew K